# .net Masked Text Box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, format-string

What is the mask for "*percentage*", in a WinForms application (VB.net)?

Comment: Do you mean: "How do I include the '%' into a MaskedTextBox ?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

> \  Escape. Escapes a mask character,
>   turning it into a literal. "`\\`" is the
>   escape sequence for a backslash.

So the mask for a % sign is \%

Before posting, I made up a quick and dirty winforms app, tried it and it works.

**Edit - added** although this next item in the documentation makes it look like just a straight % sign should work without the backslash, so I tried it and it works as well.

> All other characters  Literals. All
>   non-mask elements will appear as
>   themselves within MaskedTextBox.
>   Literals always occupy a static
>   position in the mask at run time, and
>   cannot be moved or deleted by the
>   user.

Answer (score 0):

```
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = Numeric;
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "00.00%%";
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
```

http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/59535.aspx

Comment: I doubt the OP is using a DevExpress control.