# Input Mask start with letter C in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to create an input mask which looks like this C-HG_*_*.

But because C represent option character or space in masking (VB.net). It wouldn't let me.

Please assist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [display letter A in mask maskedtextbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114466/display-letter-a-in-mask-maskedtextbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the escape element: `\`

MSDN has a [fairly nice write-up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Here's an excerpt:

> \
>   Escape. Escapes a mask character, turning it into a literal. "\\" is the escape sequence for a backslash.

Possible duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15114466/2258) and/or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3165916/2258).